# How to use jenkins to compile QT tools via code, e.g. to compile out Qt 5.15?

Tags: qt, jenkins

How to use jenkins to compile QT tools via code, e.g. to compile out Qt 5.15 ?   Can Jenkins do this please?

Comment: Jenkins is intended for regular scheduled build and is a web-site. For the task above you need regular Qt CMake and GNU tools build if the platform is Linux or any complier set supported by Qt for Windows. There is also Conan scenario-oriented build tool that is convenient for the team sharing the library as a pre-built product. All of those can be managed by Jenkins but usually it is not a normal thing to build with Jenkins scheduler. With Jenkins people do their daily build of their own product.